# AppEngine Error Code 202 - Task Queue

Tags: google-app-engine

I have task queue setup for Google App Engine in Java. It works for a long time already, but I just notice URI error in admin dashboard.

```
A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request,
causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used 
for the next request to your application. (Error code 202)
```

What caused this error?

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing this as well.  Little progress so far, but I did find the following, which may help:
Forum thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/jufkxPik1Js
Issues: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8560

Answer (score 0):

I bet that the instance is running out of memory. Are you using appstats? It can consume a large amount of memory.